# NativeScript Angular installation: Unexpected token { error

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line, syntax, nativescript

I followed the NativeScript installation guide here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup

I finished all 3 steps, but when I ran "tns doctor" at the end, I got these issues:

```
Support for Node.js ^4.0.0 is deprecated and will be removed in the next release of NativeScript. Please, upgrade to the latest Node.js LTS version.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Yok.resolveDependency (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\yok.js:338:13)
    at Yok.resolveByName (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\yok.js:315:31)
    at Yok.resolve (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\yok.js:262:25)
Error while reporting exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

---

When I tried to resolve the first issue, I ran "nodist -v" and it told me I'm on version 0.8.8. So I ran "nodist use 8" and then "nodist list" and I'm on 8.11.1. So when I run "nodist -v" again, I expect it to say 8.11.1 but it spits out 0.8.8 again.

I checked the error files listed in the syntax error and they are syntactically correct.

How do I resolve these issues?

Comment: If you need additional help, jump in the [NativeScript Community Slack](https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com), my handle there is emil.tabakov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Nodist library](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) looks abandoned and I'm not sure what might be the reason to interfere with NativeScript. We certainly haven't tested it.

My suggestion would be to remove it from your system and ensure that you have Node.JS LTS properly installed. If you need to work with multiple version of Node on your system, I recommend you to try nvm - we don't have known issues when using NativeScript with nvm.